# How to make a Portrait image fit inside a Landscape

Tags: resize

I need the image size to be 960x X 960x but the photo I have is portrait instead of landscape. I have attached the pic, as you can see, the sides are transparent currently but I need it to be covered as the background.

[image]p!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this question is attracting so many down votes.  If those who are down voting might leave a comment as to what's wrong, it would be more helpful. In my opinion this a common enough graphic design problem, and as such I feel it's a perfectly valid question to ask for ways to achieve such an edit.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways I would go about doing it.

The first is the most simple. Do a 960 x 960 crop.

[image]

The second is more complex. You could reconstruct the cut-off arms by painting them in, then mask out the figure, and create a new radial gradient background.

[image]

Comment: thanks Billy. I cant do the first one because I need the lower part of the body too. I really like the 2nd one but have no idea how to do it :(

Comment: @JasGill - but I told you how to do it . . . If your skills aren't up to scratch you can find tutorials online for masking, and for making gradients.